# How do I resolve Javax.net.ssl.handshakeException , occurring while requesting web service using REST-easy client?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, tls1.2

I have changed my webservice server from `http` to `https`. Now when I am requesting `https` web services I am getting bellow error.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("https url");
Invocation.Builder clientRequest = target.request();           
Response clientResponse = clientRequest.get();
```

Comment: If everything is ok, it should work out of the box. So probably more information is needed (are you using self-signed certificates? Does the host name match the certificate?, ...). By the way: it's TLS since 2006.

Comment: yes i am using self-signed certificates. I have made private key and configure my jboss on https.

Comment: Did you add your certificate to the clients truststore?

Comment: I have created example.keystore and added that key in configuration folder of my jboss along with that i have changes my standalone-full-ha.xml with following code
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl name="example-ssl" key-alias="example" password="****" certificate-key-file="../standalone-softplug/configuration/example.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
            </connector>

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#TrustManager. Make a copy of the default truststore, add your certificate to it (using keytool) and configure the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStore to point to your copy. Or just modify the original truststore <jre>/lib/security/cacerts, but make a backup copy.

Comment: Thank you. I have added certificate in trust store and now its working fine.